# R Frequency Table of Likert Data with Labels

Tags: r, r-markdown, expss

I try to create a frequency table from a number of variables sharing the same answer categories (Likert-typed). The result with three Variables (Question1-3) and 5 answer categories (-- to ++) should about look like this:

```
 |           |  -- |  -  |  ~  |  +  |  ++ |
 | --------- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
 | Question1 |  5% | 20% | 25% | 30% | 20% |
 | Question2 | 15% | 10% | 20% | 25% | 30% |
 | Question3 | 10% | 30% | 10% | 30% | 20% |
```

I found one working solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085852/3680150 with functions from the packages `expss` which is really helpful creating weighted and labelled frequency tables. But I have some troubles using labels, since this solution does not seem to work when the variables are labelled:

1) The solution with `expss` by @GregoryDemin from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085852/3680150

```
# The data we'll also use in the examples below.
q1<-c(2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5)
q2<-c(2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
q3<-c(2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
df<-data.frame(q1,q2,q3)

library(expss)
# add value lables for preserving empty categories
val_lab(df) = autonum(1:5)
res = df
for(each in colnames(df)){
    res = res %>% 
        tab_cells(list(each)) %>% 
        tab_cols(vars(each)) %>% 
        tab_stat_rpct(total_row_position = "none")
}


res = res %>% tab_pivot() 
# add percentage sign
recode(res[,-1]) = other ~ function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste0(round(x, 0), "%"))
res
```

The output:

```
 |    |  1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |   5 |
 | -- | -- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
 | q1 |    | 20% | 30% | 30% | 20% |
 | q2 |    | 10% | 20% | 40% | 30% |
 | q3 |    | 30% | 10% | 30% | 30% |
```

That looks good - despite that the NAs should be Zeros, shouldn't they?. How could we make sure that not used categories show 0% instead of NA?

2) Now we add some variable/value labels:

```
q1<-c(2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5)
q2<-c(2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
q3<-c(2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
df<-data.frame(q1,q2,q3)

library(expss)

# Label variables and categories
df %<>% apply_labels(q1 = "Question 1",
                     q2 = "Question 2",
                     q3 = "Question 3",
                     q1 = c("strongly agree" = 5, "agree" = 4, "neutral" = 3, "disagree" = 2, "strongly disagree" = 1),
                     q2 = c("strongly agree" = 5, "agree" = 4, "neutral" = 3, "disagree" = 2, "strongly disagree" = 1),
                     q3 = c("strongly agree" = 5, "agree" = 4, "neutral" = 3, "disagree" = 2, "strongly disagree" = 1))

# add value lables for preserving empty categories
#val_lab(df) = autonum(1:5)  # we labelled before, so no need for that anymore

# Now for the table
res = df
for(each in colnames(df)){
    res = res %>% 
        tab_cells(list(each)) %>% 
        tab_cols(vars(each)) %>% 
        tab_stat_rpct(total_row_position = "none")
}
res = res %>% tab_pivot() 
# add percentage sign
recode(res[,-1]) = other ~ function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), NA, paste0(round(x, 0), "%"))
res
```

The output:

```
 |    |        Question 1 |          |         |       |                |        Question 2 |          |         |       |
 |    | strongly disagree | disagree | neutral | agree | strongly agree | strongly disagree | disagree | neutral | agree |
 | -- | ----------------- | -------- | ------- | ----- | -------------- | ----------------- | -------- | ------- | ----- |
 | q1 |                   |      20% |     30% |   30% |            20% |                   |          |         |       |
 | q2 |                   |          |         |       |                |                   |      10% |     20% |   40% |
 | q3 |                   |          |         |       |                |                   |          |         |       |

                |        Question 3 |          |         |       |                |
 strongly agree | strongly disagree | disagree | neutral | agree | strongly agree |
 -------------- | ----------------- | -------- | ------- | ----- | -------------- |
                |                   |          |         |       |                |
            30% |                   |          |         |       |                |
                |                   |      30% |     10% |   30% |            30% |
```

The variables are not stacked anymore but standing side-by-side. It seems that this working solution breaks, if we add variable labels. Do you have an idea how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method from  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44085852/3680150 works only with variables without variable labels. Universal code with zero percents:

```
q1<-c(2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5)
q2<-c(2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5)
q3<-c(2,2,2,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
df<-data.frame(q1,q2,q3)

library(expss)

# Label variables and categories
df %<>% apply_labels(q1 = "Question 1",
                     q2 = "Question 2",
                     q3 = "Question 3",
                     q1 = c("strongly agree" = 5, "agree" = 4, "neutral" = 3, "disagree" = 2, "strongly disagree" = 1),
                     q2 = c("strongly agree" = 5, "agree" = 4, "neutral" = 3, "disagree" = 2, "strongly disagree" = 1),
                     q3 = c("strongly agree" = 5, "agree" = 4, "neutral" = 3, "disagree" = 2, "strongly disagree" = 1))

# add value lables for preserving empty categories
#val_lab(df) = autonum(1:5)  # we labelled before, so no need for that anymore

# Now for the table
res = df
for(each in colnames(df)){
    res = res %>% 
        tab_cells(total(label = "|")) %>% # suppress total label 
        tab_cols(unvr(vars(each))) %>%  # remove variable label 
        tab_stat_rpct(total_row_position = "none", label = var_lab(vars(each))) # use variable label as statistic label
}
res = res %>% tab_pivot() 
# add percentage sign
recode(res[,-1]) = other ~ function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "0%", paste0(round(x, 0), "%"))
res

# |            | strongly disagree | disagree | neutral | agree | strongly agree |
# | ---------- | ----------------- | -------- | ------- | ----- | -------------- |
# | Question 1 |                0% |      20% |     30% |   30% |            20% |
# | Question 2 |                0% |      10% |     20% |   40% |            30% |
# | Question 3 |                0% |      30% |     10% |   30% |            30% |
```