Weighted percentage cross tables with variables in the rows and their values ​in the columns
I am using the expss package to generate a cross table of weighted percentages of five categorical variables with a Likert scale and one dichotomous variable from a data frame from a survey.
The five categorical variables have the same values ​​on a Likert scale from 1 to 4.
Initially, what I want to obtain as a result is a table that expresses the weighted percentages of each value of the scales present in each categorical variable (variables according to scales).
The table should look like a cross table with the labels of the variables in the rows and the labels of the values ​​in the columns. It should look like this:




Never
Sometimes
Often
Everytime
NP
NA




Question 1
54.3
42.0
2.4
1.3
0
0.0


Question 2
46.5
47.8
3.4
2.2
0
0.1


Question 3
70.7
26.9
1.2
1.2
0
0.1


Question 4
73.8
22.1
2.2
1.7
0
0.2


Question 5
51.2
41.3
4.4
3.0
0
0.2



I have used the following code that I adapted from another post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57611802/21955095):
Df<-Data_p|>
  select(P7_1:P7_5)|>
  mutate(across(c(P7_1:P7_5),
                ~ tidyr::replace_na(., 100)))|>
  mutate(across(c(P7_1:P7_5), ~labelled(., labels = c("Never" = 1,
                                                      "Sometimes" = 2,
                                                      "Often" = 3,
                                                      "Everytime" = 4,
                                                      "NP" = 99,
                                                      "NA" = 100))))|>
  apply_labels(P7_1 = "Question 1",
               P7_2 = "Question 2",
               P7_3 = "Question 3",
               P7_4 = "Question 4",
               P7_5 = "Question 5")

res = Df
for(each in colnames(Df)){
    res = res %>% 
        tab_cells(total(label = "|")) %>% # suppress total label 
        tab_cols(unvr(vars(each))) %>%  # remove variable label 
        tab_stat_rpct(total_row_position = "none", label = var_lab(vars(each))) # use variable label as statistic label
}

res = res|>
  tab_pivot()|>
  if_na(0)|>
  tab_caption("symptoms")

The problem I have is that I can add other variables in the base that will be used for the code, such as the weighting factor or a dichotomous variable to divide the cases, because the each in the code makes the custom function put the values ​​of all the selected variables in the columns and get percentages for them as well. I only want it to do this process with the 5 likert variables. I would also like to generate another weighted table that divides each question according to a dichotomous variable as in the following example:





Never
Sometimes
Often
Everytime
NP
NA




Question 1
A
58.1
38.7
2.0
1.2
0.0
0.0



B
55,2
42,2
1,8
0,7
0,0
0,0


Question 2
A
46,1
47,9
4,2
1,5
0,0
0,3



B
46,0
49,5
2,9
1,6
0,0
0,0


Question 3
A
75,8
22,5
0,5
1,3
0,0
0,0



B
70,4
27,3
1,3
1,0
0,0
0,0


Question 4
A
78,7
18,0
0,7
2,7
0,0
0,0



B
74,0
21,6
3,3
0,8
0,0
0,3


Question 5
A
57,6
39,5
1,4
1,5
0,0
0,0



B
51,4
39,5
5,6
3,5
0,0
0,1



How could I modify the code above to get the results I expect?

I have voted to reopen your question. However, it is advisable to include some sample data with your question to make it a minimal, reproducible example. For you, this would mean running something like dput(data_p) and adding the result to a codeblock in your question as an edit. The result will look something like structure(list(...). This will give others an exact copy of your data, which in turn, will make it easier to provide an answer.
